# How old was Ender objectively at the start of Speaker for the Dead

Tags: orson-scott-card, chronology, age, speaker-for-the-dead

In Chapter 2 of Speaker, it says this

> After all, the Bugger Wars were more than three thousand years ago; it was now the year 1948 SC, counting from the year the Starways Code was established, and Ender had destroyed the buggers in the year 1180 BSC.

A few chapters later, there is this conversation between him and Jane:

> “How old am I?” he asked.
>   “It has been 3081 years since you were born. But your subjective age is 36 years and 118 days.”

Now, 1180 + 1948 = 3128. How could he have been born *less* than 3128 years earlier?

Comment: I'm beginning to think OS Card was math-challenged.

Comment: him and JK Rowling need to start a club.

Comment: Perhaps the Starways Code took around 60 years to develop, and there's overlap in the middle of BSC and SC years?  </shot-in-the-dark>

Answer (score 5):

You are of course assuming that Jane and Ender are counting the Earth years since his birth in the same way as the Starways Congress counts their "years".

If it's been 3000+ years since the destruction of the buggers , it's quite likely that the common year has shortened or lengthened. Even a discrepancy of 1 day would put the calculations a decade out over a period of 3000 "years"

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that instantaneous ansible communication has revealed that every planet in the universe has a gravity field and therefore under the effects of time dilation to a small degree. Even in our own day, relativity and time dilation was first confirmed by clocks that had been synchronized before one was launched into a retrograde orbit. Dilation was detected within a short time. If we were to suddenly find ourselves able to experience time without a gravity field (ansibles), then we would also have to come up with a time-keeping system that reflects no distortion from a gravity field and would HAVE to be a compromise of all the Hundred Worlds, since every different world has different gravity and relative motion within other local fields such as a moon or moons, the parent sun's,  position in the galactic field, et cetera. Any small discrepancy would add up quickly.